# streaming video with peerjs webrtc from android webview is too slow

Tags: android, video, android-webview, webrtc, peerjs

I have an android application that sends the camera stream through a webview through peerjs (webrtc) the web application on the browser receives the video and streams it.

Things are working but the video on the web is too slow and the image freezes for some time before getting the second image...

Is there a way to make the resolution lower ? or buffer the video on the web application ?  or can it be something wrong with my implementation ?

**Android Webview code:**

```
        initVideo = function(videoSourceValue) {

        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        navigator.getUserMedia({video:  {optional: [{
                                                    sourceId: videoSourceValue
                                                     }]
                                          }
                                },function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        $('#peerId').text("calling : " + SERVER_PEER_ID);
         var mediaConnection = peer.call(SERVER_PEER_ID, stream);
          mediaConnection.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
            // Show stream in some video/canvas element.
          });
        },function(e){
                console.log('failed',e);
        });
    }
```

**Web part:**

```
   function getVideoStream() {
    PEER.on('call', function(call) {
        var mediaConnection = navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
            call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
            call.on('stream', onReceiveStream);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('Failed to get local stream' ,err);
        });
    });
}


    function onReceiveStream(stream){
        console.log('received stream');
        $('video').prop('src',window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));

}
```

Thanks

**Update 1**

I tried to add `{reliable : true}`, still having the same issue.

I'm also sending location data to the server, and it seems that the video streams and location data are sent together periodically (the chart on the web showing speed and the video move at the same time) but the frame rate is too slow.

Comment: Honestly, I would simply suggest moving away from a webview and going with native (you have much more control that way). I know this is not really an answer :(.   You can also try setting video stream parameters in the webview code, not sure if it would take or not.

Comment: I'm open to using the native android way, i just found that it was much more complicated (On web i'm simply using peerjs), if you have a link or a library for simple video streaming through android directly it would be perfect

Comment: Do you care to do a 2 way call or will a one way call suffice? On web (I assume chrome), can you go to chrome://webrtc-internals and paste the stats you get on incoming and outgoing video streams? Let the call run for few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

When you establish the video/audio stream you can specify some constraints...

```
var videoOptions = (isCordova) ? {audio: true, video: true} :
                    {  audio: true, 
                      video: {
                        mandatory: {
                               maxWidth: 640,
                               maxHeight: 360,
                               // maxAspectRatio:4/3,
                               // maxFrameRate:1
                              },
                        quality: 7,
                        width: { ideal: 320 },
                        height: { ideal: 240 }
                      }
                    };

navigator.getUserMedia(videoOptions, function (stream) {
```

In the above code, if you are on a device (android/ios) you don't get to choose, but you can control it on the browser. A quality of 5 is the level that the video driver author deemed as an acceptable trade off between quality and bandwidth. Limiting the dimensions of the picture helps too.

See this link for mode details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: When i set it from the browser, won't I be setting the value of the stream from the browser to the device ?

Comment: That is true, some control is better than no control. Desktops tend to assume they have good bandwidth available, so it makes a difference to limit what is being sent. I think the default in the mobile device is lower anyway. In my experimentation it does make a difference

Comment: @Mikkel do you know where the documentation referencing the "quality" attribute is ?

Comment: I don't know if there is any on quality, I used a number between 1 and 9. Play with it and see

Answer (score 3):

My issue was completely unrelated to bandwidth, I simply didn't put autoplay on the video tag , so the video was only refreshing when a redraw was happening.

Thanks a lot for your answers they really give insight on how things work in webrtc.